# Migrate the .git folders structure for Submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

In old versions of git, before 1.7.8, the git folder of the submodule was located inside the submodule folder

```
RootProject/Submodule/.git
```

Starting from 1.7.8 this structure is changed

```
When populating a new submodule directory with "git submodule init",
the $GIT_DIR metainformation directory for submodules is created inside
$GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/ directory of the superproject and referenced
via the gitfile mechanism. This is to make it possible to switch
between commits in the superproject that has and does not have the
submodule in the tree without re-cloning.
```

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt

So now it is being created at inside the .git/modules of the root project

```
RootProject/.git/modules/Submodule/
```

and the .git folder inside the submodule is converted to a file that contains a relative path to the git folder in the root

```
gitdir: ../.git/modules/Submodule
```

So is there any way to migrate from the old structure to the new structure without losing the local history(i.e. local branches, stashes,...)?

Comment: Shouldn't simply moving the dir and creating the `.git` file suffice? Is there some issue with that approach that I just don't understand right now?

Comment: I don't know whether this will be fixed by only moving folders or there are some other files needed to be changed in the migration process, if i'm sure that this is the only needed, I can create a batch or java code to move and .git folders to the new location.

Comment: I Noticed that git should be changed to add worktree entry, but is there is any thing else should be changed? if there is a ready batch or git command that can do that without affective the local history